# How to properly add a series of checkboxes to Search Options?

Tags: jquery, search, custom-component

I've been tasked with extending the normal Search Options (created with Component Creator, if it matters) to be located on the left of the page, and include a long list of various checkboxes to filter the search - a common feature of large ecommerce sites.  I've created a series of custom Joomla input fields that render the checkboxes just as expected, and the filtering itself actually works just fine.

The problem is that the **Clear Search** button doesn't clear the checked boxes.  The custom form field is in the form's XML, and is included in `$config['filter_fields']` of the model, and works as a filter just as expected.

So is there an additional entry somewhere that I need to address for Clearing to work?  I can't see anything that is being posted that triggers anything, only a class on the button `js-stools-btn-clear`, that gets used in  `jquery.searchtools.js`, and that's where my trail goes cold.

My gut tells me that javascript is clearing the `val` of the filter fields somewhere/somehow, and the core code isn't equipped to clear an array of checkboxes.

Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not done this before so this could be the wrong approach, but will give it a shot anyway.

Looking at the default **clear** button for filters, it contains the following `onclick` attribute:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('filter_search').value='';this.form.submit();"
```

What this does is empties the input field, then resets the form.

Seeing as you have checkboxes, you can also clear them, then reset the form, for example:

**JS:**

```
function resetCheckboxes(source) 
{
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("somename");

    for (var i=0, n=checkboxes.length; i<n; i++) 
    {
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
}
```

**Checkboxes:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="somename" />
<input type="checkbox" name="somename" />
<input type="checkbox" name="somename" />
```

**Button:**

```
onclick="resetCheckboxes('this'); document.getElementById('filter_search').value='';this.form.submit();"
```

This above is of course assuming your checkboxes are using the same `name=""`, which in the case I've provided, is `somename`

Hope this helps

Comment: Interesting, my Clear button does not have that - must be a Component-Creator thing.  All I've got is `<button data-original-title="Clear" title="" class="btn hasTooltip js-stools-btn-clear" type="button">Clear</button>`.  I'll try your suggestion nonetheless, and see if it and the CC approach get along with each other.

Comment: Ahh, in which case the `jquery.searchtools.js` file, most like looks for the `js-stools-btn-clear` class and performs the magic in there. Would you be able to use add the contents of the JS file to [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/) ?

Comment: I wanted to avoid messing with that .js file, so I took your suggestion, and  initially, it didn't  work because the native searchtools javascript was being fired before my reset code.  To get around that, I simply used a different class name on the clear button that the JS was tied to and, used my own `form.submit()` on *that* class name.  Works perfectly now.    You REALLY, really want those flowers, don't you.

Comment: More than anything haha. Glad you got it working on the end :)